# What is the simplest way to create a weight matrix bases on how frequent each element appear in the matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix

This is the input matrix

```
 7     9     6
 8     7     9
 7     6     7
```

Based on the frequency their appearance in the matrix (Note. these values are for explanation purpose. I didn't pre-calculate them in advance. That why I ask this question)

```
 number frequency
 6      2
 7      4
 8      1
 9      2
```

and the output I expect is

```
 4     2     2
 1     4     2
 4     2     4
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a three-line solution. First prepare the input:

```
X = [7 9 6;8 7 9;7 6 7];
```

Now do:

```
[a m n] = unique(X);

b = hist(X(:),a);

c = reshape(b(n),size(X));
```

Which gives this value for `c`:

```
4     2     2
1     4     2
4     2     4
```

If you also wanted the frequency matrix, you can get it with this code:

```
[a b']
```

Comment: more straightforward than this one?!? :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a code with for-loop (`a` is input matrix, `freq` - frequency matrix with 2 columns):

```
weight = zeros(size(a));
for k = 1:size(freq,1)
    weight(a==freq(k,1)) = freq(k,2);
end
```

Comment: `a` and `freq` are input matrices. Updated the answer.

Comment: Sorry that my question was uncleared earlier. I didn't have the pre-calculated frequency. What I had is only the input matrix and I updated my question regarding this

Comment: look to my answer for calculating frequency

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it can be solved without loops, but my code looks like:

```
M = [7     9     6  ;
     8     7     9  ;
     7     6     7  ;];

number = unique(M(:));
frequency = hist(M(:), number)';
map = containers.Map(number, frequency);

[height width] = size(M);
result = zeros(height, width); %allocate place

for i=1:height
  for j=1:width
    result(i,j) = map(M(i,j));
  end
end
```